# Is a mutex necessary when only inc/decrementing a variable?

Tags: c, synchronization, pthreads, mutex

I have a struct with some integers field, like

```
struct s {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int max;
};
struct s mystruct = {0, 0, 0, 0}; // Global var
```

And then I have N threads that sometimes have to do things like `++` or `--` on the first three fields, and sometimes have to read them and then update the `max` field. Do I have to use a mutex here? And if yes, is it needed only when reading/updating `max` or always? Why? If I just increment or decrement the first three fields, does it matter if a thread runs before another?

Comment: It's like asking if you only need to lock the front door of your house, the back door is only used for occasional visitors and isn't so important.

Comment: see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30150903/necessity-of-pthread-mutex

Comment: You could use `stdatomic.h`

Comment: Useful exercise: https://deadlockempire.github.io

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to synchronize the access to the variables if the operations you are performing are not atomic.
Consider a scenario of a single variable `a` having initial value of, say, 5.
Now we have two threads T1 and T2, both want to increment it. How increment operation is broken down, in case it is not atomic (just an example, it could be some other way)?

1) Read `a` value into a temp location.
2) Increment and write the temp location back into `a`.

Now consider a scenario T1 is performing this operation first, and then pre-empted by T2 after completing step 1 only:

T1: 1) Read `a` into `temp1` => `temp1=5`
T2: 1) Read `a` into `temp2` => `temp2=5`
T2:  2) Write `temp2+1` into `a` => `a=6`
T1:  2) Write `temp1+1` into `a` => `a=6`

So the final value of `a` will be `6` and not `7` as you would expect.

Answer (score 10):

The universal rule of concurrency is this: If a memory location is accessed concurrently in a non-atomic way, and not all accesses are reads, then the accesses must be ordered. Ordering can be imposed either by serializing access through locking a mutex, or by some lower-level operation like an ordered atomic access or an ordered fence.

The only time you're allowed to have *unordered* accesses if *all* of the accesses are reads. E.g. multiple threads can read a (non-atomic) constant without ordering.

Comment: The technical concepts that define "ordering" are "happens-before" and "synchronizes-with".

Comment: The accesses do *not* have to ordered. If the accesses are atomic with `memory_order_relaxed`, they are not ordered.